# Call by ID a load element in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is that possible?

I have a HTML file where I load elements by an external .js file with this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#redessociales2').livequery(function() {
          $("#piedepagina2").load("genericbody.html #piedepagina");
        });

});
```

Where #piedepagina is this:

```
<div id= "piedepagina">
<center>
    <br/>
    <p>
Todos los derechos reservados.
<span id="changestyle">dise&ntilde;o alternativo</span></br>

    </p>
</center>
</div>
```

In the same .js I have this:

```
if($.cookie("css")) {
if($.cookie("css")==1){
    $("#linkestilo").attr("href", "../css/post.css");
}
else{
    $("#linkestilo").attr("href", "../css/post2.css");
}   
 }

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#changestyle").click(function(e){
    var estilo1="../css/post.css"
    var estilo2="../css/post2.css"

    if($("#linkestilo").attr("href")==estilo1){
        $("#linkestilo").attr("href", estilo2);
        $.cookie("css", "2", {expires: 365, path: '/'});
    }

    else{
        $("#linkestilo").attr("href", estilo1);
        $.cookie("css", "1", {expires: 365, path: '/'});
    }

    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: '0px'
   },
   1500);
   return false;
});
```

});

This code change the style of the web, and works perfect if I put the HTML code directly in HTML file, but when I move HTML code to another HTML file (I need to do this way) it's brokes.

I think that can be cause I'm calling an element by ID and this ID it's not phisically in the original HTML file.
How can I solve it?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Is your js at the bottom of the page? If not can you trying putting your js at the bottom and let me know the results

Comment: why would document.ready need to be at the end of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Because you load the html from an external file, `$("#changestyle")` is most likely not loaded into the DOM when `$(document).ready()` fires and so the `click()` is not attached.

Which version of jQuery are you using? I haven't used LiveQuery in a long time, but since v1.7+ you should be using the [on() event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Change your existing `$("#changestyle").click()` handler to:

```
$("#piedepagina2").on("click", "#changestyle", function(e){
    // run your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for help me!
I finally found the correct code, I share with you:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#piedepagina2")
        .load("genericbody.html #piedepagina")
        .delegate("#changestyle", "click", function (e){
    var estilo1="../css/post.css"
    var estilo2="../css/post2.css"

    if($("#linkestilo").attr("href")==estilo1){
        $("#linkestilo").attr("href", estilo2);
        $.cookie("css", "2", {expires: 365, path: '/'});
    }

    else{
        $("#linkestilo").attr("href", estilo1);
        $.cookie("css", "1", {expires: 365, path: '/'});
    }

    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: '0px'
   },
   1500);
   return false;
});

});
```

I hope help people with same problem!

Bye! thx again!